# AngularJs - How do I create one variable/one input that would be used in multiple controllers?

Tags: angularjs, syntax, controller

I need help with syntax.

I'm trying to create 2 user inputs stored as variables, that would be used within 3 separate controllers.

What I'm trying to do is create a table where each row is a controller in itself. Based on the numbers the user inputs, each row would calculate various fields.

'Standard Eye Level' and 'ImageAspectRatio' need to go into each of the three controllers but I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be.

Please take a look at my plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ptHhwmaKdeB4CfYEvdlL?p=preview

```
var BDMApp = angular.module('BDMApp', []);
var StandardEyeLevel = Number(ctrl.StandardEyeLevel || 0);
var ImageAspectRatio = Number(ctrl.ImageAspecRatio || 0);

BDMApp.controller('BDMFarViewController', [function() {
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.BDMCalc = function() {
  var BDMFarViewImgHeight = Number(ctrl.BDMFarViewImgHeight || 0);
  var BDMFarViewDistFloor = Number(ctrl.BDMFarViewDistFloor || 0);
  var BDMFarViewMinPerElm = Number(ctrl.BDMFarViewMinPerElm || 0);
  ctrl.BDMFarViewImgOffSetAns = BDMFarViewDistFloor - StandardEyeLevel;
  ctrl.BDMFarViewImgWidthAns = BDMFarViewImgHeight * ImageAspectRatio;
  ctrl.BDMFarViewFarViewAns = BDMFarViewDistFloor * BDMFarViewMinPerElm * 200;
  ctrl.BDMFarViewViewRatAns = ctrl.BDMFarViewFarViewAns / BDMFarViewDistFloor;
  ctrl.BDMFarViewVVFAns = BDMFarViewDistFloor + ctrl.BDMFarViewImgOffSetAns;
  ctrl.BDMFarViewCloseViewAns = ctrl.BDMFarViewVVFAns * 1.732;
  ctrl.BDMFarViewViewRatAns = ctrl.BDMFarViewCloseViewAns / BDMFarViewImgHeight;
  ctrl.BDMFarviewNominalViewDepthAns = ctrl.BDMFarViewFarViewAns - ctrl.BDMFarViewCloseViewAns;
}
}]);
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want share data among multiple controllers, you can use $rootScope. But it is not recommended. So, use a service to store data and use it in multiple controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want share data between controllers you should write the shareable code in services.

**myService.js**

```
app.service('myService', [function(){
        var self = this;
        self.img;
        self.img.StandardEyeLevel;
        self.img.ImageAspectRatio;
        self.getValues = function(passedVal){
           self.img[any one of the img property] = passedVal;
           return self.img;
        }

        return {
           'getValues': self.getValues
        }
}])
```

Now, in controller inject the service and call the function with the value to set to upgrade it from different controllers.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
   $scope.StandardEyeLevel = myService.getValues();
}])
```

This is not a good practice but just saying understanding purpose of how controllers can share data with services.

**Note:** replace below code with your plunker code. Observe console and output

```
<head>
   <title>Share data between controllers in AngularJs with $rootScope</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
   <script>
      var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.run(function($rootScope) {
         $rootScope.userData = {};
         $rootScope.userData.firstName = "";
         $rootScope.userData.lastName = "";
      });
      app.controller("firstController", ["myService", "$scope", "$rootScope", function(myService, $scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.userData.firstName = myService.getVal("Hello", '');
        console.log('aaaaaaaaaa', $scope.userData.firstName)
      }]);
      app.controller("secondController", ["myService", "$scope", "$rootScope", function(myService, $scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.userData.lastName = myService.getVal('', "World");
        console.log('aaaaaaaaaa', $scope.userData.lastName)
      }]);
      app.service('myService', function(){
        var self = this;
        self.names = {};
        self.getVal = function(fname, lname){
          if(fname){
           self.names.fname = fname;
          }
          if(lname){
           self.names.lname = lname;
          }
         return self.names;
        }
        return self;
      })
   </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="firstController">
      <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="userData.firstName.fname">
      <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="userData.lastName.lname">
   <hr>
   </div>
   <div ng-controller="secondController"> Username: <b> {{userData.firstName.fname}}</b>
   <br>
   Lastname:<b>{{userData.lastName.lname}}</b>      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain using my variable names. I've tried it myself, but I'm struggling to get it working. How do I tie this into the front end? Can you show me? https://plnkr.co/edit/yWV3KhNnLvgcuOABJm9M?p=preview

Comment: I have edited my answer. Copy it in your plunker and observe the outputs

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can also use `$rootScope` for sharing data between controllers

**Script Code**

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.run(function($rootScope) {
         $rootScope.userData = {};
         $rootScope.userData.firstName = "ram";
         $rootScope.userData.lastName = "gopal";
      });
      app.controller("firstController", function($scope, $rootScope) {
      });
      app.controller("secondController", function($scope, $rootScope) {
      });
```

Here's the [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/yWV3KhNnLvgcuOABJm9M?p=preview) for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare them as **Global variables** as explained below.

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
var Global_User = null;
var Global_Token = null;
var Global_IsLoggedIn = false;

myApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, DatabaseService) {
    $scope.login = function (Username, Password) {
        $http.get(BaseServiceURL + "api/Token/GetToken?UserName=" + Username + "&Password=" + Password + "")
       .success(function (data) {
            DatabaseService.session.setItem('userName', Global_User);
            DatabaseService.session.setItem('token', Global_Token);
            LoginNavigator.pushPage('Home.html');
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $http) {
    if (Global_IsLoggedIn == true) {
        $scope.greeting = "Hi " + nameCase(Global_User);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm sorry, but the example code above leaves me with more questions. Can you show me how to implement this using my code? A global variable is exactly what I want to create, but I'm not sure how to tie that in with the front end so the user decides what value goes in the Global Variable. Here is the link again. Thank you for any help: https://plnkr.co/edit/ptHhwmaKdeB4CfYEvdlL?p=preview